# gdb disable breakpoint in particular thread

Tags: gdb, breakpoints, conditional-breakpoint

Is it possible to disable gdb breakpoints on a per-thread basis?

I have a breakpoint which triggers every 100 milliseconds in the background worker thread. But I need to debug the same location in any other threads. So it would be cool to disable breakpoint only in the background worker thread. Is it possible?

Maybe I can disable thread by adding some specially crafted condition to this breakpoint when I know thread's number?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Gdb provides two convenience variables, `$_thread` and `$_gthread` (the latter being pretty new), which can be used in conditions to refer to the current thread.

So, once the worker thread has started, you can use `info thread` to find its number.  Then you can change your breakpoint (supposing for this example that it is breakpoint 2) like:

```
(gdb) cond 2 $_thread != 57
```

Comment: Thank you. This is what I was looking for.

Comment: I was too, but found a case where it does not work as I've interpreted it to work: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76584590/how-to-make-gdb-stop-trapping-on-breakpoints-in-other-threads-under-set-schedule