# How to make GDB stop trapping on breakpoints in other threads under set scheduler-locking off conditions?

Tags: multithreading, gdb

Why doesn't `set scheduler-locking off` stop trapping on breakpoints on threads *other than* the current thread completely, but only trap on the current thread?

[gdb disable breakpoint in particular thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37978625/gdb-disable-breakpoint-in-particular-thread) was close to what I was looking for, but not quite:

Imagine I have N breakpoints during a debug session. Having to execute a command such as `cond 2 $_thread != 57` (as given by the [gdb disable breakpoint in particular thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37978625/gdb-disable-breakpoint-in-particular-thread) answer) where the `2` will have to be repeated for all N breakpoints. But if I have no choice but to do that, then why is that necessary?

### Update 2023-06-29 14:18:38:

And apparently the `cond`itional breakpoint logic does not work as I would have expected it to:

[image]

### Version info

FYI: This is on a ancient Linux machine:

```
$ lsb_release -r -i
Distributor ID: RedHatEnterpriseWorkstation
Release:    6.10
```

On this version of GDB:

```
(gdb) show version
GNU gdb (GDB) 8.0.50.20171024-git
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-pc-linux-gnu".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.
For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word".
(gdb)
```

Comment: If you only want to break in thread 2, then you should use `$_thread == 2` as condition, and not `!=`.

Answer (score 0):

> Why doesn't set scheduler-locking off stop trapping on breakpoints on threads other than the current thread completely, but only trap on the current thread?

Because `scheduler-locking` doesn't have *anything* to do with breakpoints.

What it does is control whether `next`, `continue`, etc. resume all threads (default `scheduler-locking off`), or just one (current) thread (not default, `scheduler-locking on`).

If you set `scheduler-locking on`, then only the current thread will run and only that thread can hit any breakpoints.

If you set it to `off`, any thread may run and if that thread hits a breakpoint, then *all* threads will stop and GDB will switch to the thread which caused everything to stop.

This is all working as intended.

---

> How to make GDB stop trapping on breakpoints in other threads under set scheduler-locking off conditions?

By creating breakpoints that are specific to a particular thread. This breakpoint will *only* trigger in a particular thread, and not in any other threads:

```
(gdb) break foo thread 3
```

> Imagine I have N breakpoints during a debug session

If you wanted these breakpoints to only apply to certain threads, then make them thread-specific when you create them.